# Are postpositive adjectives examples of reduced relative clauses?

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses, postpositive-adjectives

> We have a variety of products [that are] available to purchase.

> He found a house [that was] devoid of life.

Traditionally, adjectives precede their associated noun. This, however, isn't the case with postpositive adjectives. Is this another example of a reduced relative clause?

Comment: I wonder too. All postpositive adjectives are reduced relative clauses?

Comment: An adjective is not a clause. And I think you mean postpositioned, not postpositive.

Comment: @Lambie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective Postpositive is an acceptable term.

Comment: Yes, absolutely but devoid of life is not an adjective per se.  It's a predicate OR with that is, a noun phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *We have a variety of products* [*available to purchase*].
>
> *He found a house* [*devoid of life*].

No, the bracketed elements are not some kind of relative clause, though they are modifiers.

They are adjective phrases functioning as post-head modifiers of the nominals "variety of products" and "house".

Nouns accept a very wide range of post-head modifiers: we don't want to call them all relative clauses. In any case, it is a crucial property of relative clauses that they always contain an element -- actually present or understood -- that is anaphorically related to an antecedent. No such element exists in the modifiers in the above examples.

Comment: Would you say that the term 'reduced relative clause' is redundant? This link (https://www.thoughtco.com/reduced-relative-clauses-1211107) and a few others I have consulted use this description quite often. Additionally, before I had knowledge about participle clauses, postpositive adjectives, and prepositional phrases, I would often convert them to relative clauses in my head to check that my writing made sense. I always assumed that these different forms were derived from relative clauses, even though I didn't know what one was at the time.